# Ruby Selenium begin rescue

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, nosuchelementexception

I use Cucumber with Ruby and Selenium. 
Here is scenario where I need to check that element is not on the page
When I do such within Cucumber step

```
    Step file:
    begin
     expect(checkout_page.city_acctdetails.displayed?).to eql false
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
     puts "City dropdown is not present"
     false
    end
```

it works like a charm.
When I try to do something like by putting as method in another file/helper

```
 RubyHelper.rb file
   def self.not_present(locator)
    begin
      locator.displayed?
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
      puts "Not present"
      false
    end
  end
```

so when I change in Cucumber Step file

```
RubyHelper.not_present(checkout_page.city_acctdetails)
```

I get error:
Unable to locate element: {} (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError)

Require statements:

```
  #BDD framework that makes feature files running
require 'cucumber'

#Control remote browsers
require 'selenium-webdriver'

#Run tests in parallel
require 'parallel_tests'

#Use expect().to for verifying result
require 'rspec'

#Key value format for storing text data
require 'yaml'
```

Comment: Not to be nit-picky, but if the exception is triggered, don't you want not_present to return true?And don't you want false just after locator.displayed? ?  Dealing with negatives is such fun.  This is why I stick with positives. What do your requires look like in your helper file?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 Because depends on scenario, I might have element present or not, so I am making assestion on element not being present as I am expecting so

Comment: Vanatomas You know what you mean.  But other people who read it don't have access to your head.  All they have is what they read.  In six weeks you may not remember what you intended either.  I have learned to write simply, avoid negatives, and to have methods mean what they say. Just friendly advice.

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 sure thing, my question was about rescue statement, not about writing negatives scenarios. In my case it is needed for validation depends on lang or region and so on. Thx

Comment: can you list your helper file's require statments?

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 it is listed on top, under RubyHelper.rb section

Comment: Can you add it to your question above so that I can see them. :-)

Comment: @MikeJRamsey56 what exactly you are looking for from require statement?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby Cucumber magic depends on something called the [World object](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World).  To make your RubyHelper file available to your step definitions you need to:

1. Wrap the helper methods in a module
2. Tell Cucumber to include the module into each World object for each Scenario

RubyHelper.rb file

```
require 'cucumber'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'rspec'
module MyHelper
  def not_present(locator)
    begin
      locator.displayed?
    rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
      puts "Not present"
      false
    end
  end
end
World(MyHelper)
```

Comment: Should have seen this first thing.

Comment: getting undefined method `World' for... Should I add additional gem? Using Rspec

Comment: @Vanatomas Are you running with the latest cucumber? I am running 2.3.2.

Comment: I just put together a quick test and it worked for me.

Comment: yes, cucumber 2.3.2 version. Also, can I have module inside of class?

Comment: Just a module.  The syntax is different for a class.  Remember that the World object is a mix in.  It adds the methods that you define to the step definition files.

Comment: ok dropped into another file, was able to pass "World" error, but execution did throw NoSuchElement Error, like to square one I had with Class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106029/discussion-between-vanatomas-and-mikejramsey56).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to `sleep` or wait for that event load. It something that when you run your test, the test was executed but the element is not yet there.